# How to know if the Service Fabric cluster upgrade is done in a microservice

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

What I need to do, is to do something (in one of the microservices) once the whole cluster's upgrade is done.

Is there any event or something that notifies the services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write 'an event or something that notifies the services' with the help of either of these.

1. You get the [Get Cluster Upgrade Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-api-getclusterupgradeprogress) as Azure REST API.
2. You can leverage [Get-​Service​Fabric​Cluster​Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/get-servicefabricclusterupgrade?view=azureservicefabricps) if you wish to do it using Azure Service Fabric Powershell way.

---

Apparently there is no provision which you wish to have. Just for an example I deployed an app in Azure service fabric cluster.

A part of response in `output` window was:

```
3>Started executing script 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus'.
3>[void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -TimeoutSec:10 -WarningAction:'SilentlyContinue' -ConnectionEndpoint:'sfcluster.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:19000'); Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModuleServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1'; Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus -ApplicationName 'fabric:/SortApp' -ErrorAction Stop
3>The application has started.
3>Service Status:
3>fabric:/SortApp/SortService is ready.
3>
3>The application is ready.
3>Finished executing script 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus'.
```

This clearly shows that script of `Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus` is used instead of 'an event or something that notifies the services'.

Comment: thanks, yeah true, we can poll the API till the upgrade is done, I was just wondering if there is anything in the fabric SDK that would notify classes. So that I don't have to add the cluster API endpoint in my settings, as we got multiple environments and each environment got its own cluster. It'd be good if I could just handle and event in my service.

Comment: @akazemis: Apparently there is no provision as such. I'll be happy if this feature is added too.